# Order of times and addition functions in a java/kotlin equation

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm completing the [Kotlin Koans Operators Overloading](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Conventions/Operators%20overloading/Task.kt) exercise and am mean to implement a date arithmetic like so:

```
today + YEAR * 2 + WEEK * 3 + DAY * 5
```

My question is, will this operate like a regular mathematical equation where multiplication will be executed first?

```
today + (YEAR * 2) + WEEK * 3 + (DAY * 5) 

today.add(YEAR * 2).add(WEEK * 3).add(DAY * 5)
```

If so I assume the `times()` operator overloader is what I should perform first in the exercise and *then* write the `add()` overloader code.

Answer (score 2):

It will indeed work the same as a mathmatical expression.

The [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) page states (emphasis mine):

> Kotlin allows us to provide implementations for a predefined set of operators on our types. These operators have fixed symbolic representation (like + or *) **and fixed precedence**.

And the Grammar page [lists](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions) the precedence of operators, where `*` is above `+`.

So the `times` function is called first, and its result is passed as the argument of the `plus` function.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is designed to keep the order of precedence for operators exactly the same as mathematics, yes.